# how to write data into a long excel file using matlab?

Tags: excel, matlab

I'm trying to write data into a long excel file using matlab and my problem is that when the number of columns in the file goes beyond 27, the columns are marked as 'AA' 'AB' and so forth. 
I am using the command:

```
>index=find(strncmp(xlRaw(2,:),'title',5));
```

to find the index number of the columns I need to write into. this gives me the numbers of the columns which I need to translate into characters. 'A', 'B'... 'AA'...

to do this transformation I'm using:

```
>writeIndex=[char(index(1)-27+'A')];
```

and it works as long as the index equals 27 or less. when some are bigger, I need to use this loop:

```
>for ii=1:length(index);
    if index(ii)<27
        writeIndex(ii)={char(index(ii)-1+'A')};
    else writeIndex(ii)={['A',char(index(ii)-27+'A')]};
    end
 end
```

Does anyone know a more efficient way to do this? This program takes a while to run as it is, so I'm trying to use a minimum of loops. I would like to perform this simple action without one.

Does anyone know how this could be done?

Comment: there are a few things, each one into a different set of columns, some are to mark progress, some are frame numbers, and so forth. i don't think it's relevant to the question.

Comment: Yes, I can see how clearly illustrating the problem you want people to solve for you is totally irrelevant to the question.

Comment: the question is how to transform index numbers into excel column letters in an efficient way. do you think the data itself is a factor here?

Comment: Yes, because knowing the size of the data you are trying to write, its source, and its destination allows us to determine the best method to write the data to the file.

Comment: all of the data i'm writing into the file is a number or a few words, they go into a single box in the excel file. i have the row number because i'm working on a single row at a time. i'm extracting the column number using the command i wrote in the question.

Comment: Ok, if you're dead set on doing it this way use Hoki's `excel_column` function here: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/31860247/how-to-find-the-last-column-index-in-excel-with-matlab/31862155#31862155

Comment: One thing to realize: it is not likely that the creation of excel column names is going to take a significant amount of time. (Compared to the time requires for the actual xlswrite)But of course you could measure it if you are not sure.

Answer (score 0):

The normal way to write to an xls file is by using `xlswrite`, here is an example of writing a 100 by 100 matrix to a file:

```
 xlswrite('writefile.xls' ,rand(100))
```

If you only want to change part of the sheet, you may want to use the following workflow:

1. Load everything into matlab using `xlsread`
2. Change the variable by editing the resulting variable
3. Write everything by using `xlswrite`

Writing a lot at once is (much) faster than writing things one by one. Make sure to check out `doc xlswrite` for additional options.

Comment: i am, of course, using xlsread and xlswrite. but i'm not creating a new file from scrtach. i am reading and writing into a database file that i need to write only specific parts of. that is why i need an efficient way to create the indeces that are required for the xlswrite command.

Comment: @LightL I don't see `xlswrite` anywhere in your code. Please create a minimal reproducible example. It should have 1. Inputs (or code to generate inputs) 2. Code that someone can just copy in their own matlab to make it work -- These two together should of course be set up in a way that they clearly illustrate the problem.

Comment: xlRange=[WriteIndex{jj},rowToWrite,':',WriteIndex{jj},rowToWrite];
                xlswrite(xlfileName,{'yes'},'sheet1',xlRange);

Comment: these are the commands i'm using to write into the file:          'code' xlRange=[WriteIndex{jj},rowToWrite,':',WriteIndex{jj},rowToWrite];
                xlswrite(xlfileName,{'yes'},'sheet1',xlRange);                                       unfortunately, i won't be able to publish the excel file i'm using. as i mentioned, it is a data base file and contains the names of videos and information about them. the program analizes the videos and marks progress and certain data like fps and problematic frames in the excel file.

Comment: @LightL Rather than placing code here in the comments, please update your question to contain everything that is needed. If you cannot upload your file (or a similar one) consider including code for creating a dummy input, for example by something like this `xlswrite('myinput.xls',rand(10000,100))`