# xlswrite without overwriting

Tags: excel, matlab, user-interface

I need help with exporting GUI data to Excel with .xlswrite. Currently I am able to write it in to Excel but because I have to repeat the entire process for a total of 20 times, it means I have to store at least 20 lines into Excel. I have tried searching online but there are websites that says use "xlsappend" which I don't understand how to use and seem to be getting an error.

Is there any way to go about doing it?

My current code:

```
xlswrite('File.xls', {'SubjectID:'},'Sheet1','A1');
xlswrite('File.xls', {name},'Sheet1','A2');
xlswrite('File.xls', {'Radiobutton: '},'Sheet1','B1');
xlswrite('File.xls', {Radiobutton},'Sheet1','B2');
```

Also, is it possible to make a line in between this and the next set of data?

Answer (score 0):

I would suggest you didn't hard-code the cells where you want to write your data but instead used a dynamically changing range, for example in a loop.

The most intuitive way to do this would be using Excel's row-column notation (i.e. `R1C1` , instead of `A1`; see also: [link1](https://excelmate.wordpress.com/2013/04/22/excel-r1c1-reference-style-vs-a1/), [link2](https://support.office.com/en-us/article/ADDRESS-function-d0c26c0d-3991-446b-8de4-ab46431d4f89)). However, as of MATLAB 2015b Excel doesn't accept this notation, which has to be converted to `A1`-style, using code such as [this](http://cn.mathworks.com/matlabcentral/newsreader/view_thread/337504):

```
function a1name = GenerateExcelA1(rows,cols)
    a1name = [char(base2dec(dec2base(cols,26)',26)+64)' num2str(rows)];
end
```

(You can put the above in a separate file, e.g. `GenerateExcelA1.m`, or in the same file if it's a multifunction script)

Your code would then would look something like this:

```
%// Definitions:
SUBJECT_TAG_COL = 1;
SUBJECT_VAL_COL = 2;
RADIO_TAG_COL = 3;
RADIO_VAL_COL = 4;

for ind1=1:numLines %// if you also want empty lines, replace with ind1=1:2:2*numLines
%// Make sure data is available, then:
    xlswrite('File.xls', {'SubjectID:'},'Sheet1',GenerateExcelA1(ind1,SUBJECT_TAG_COL));
    xlswrite('File.xls', {name},'Sheet1',GenerateExcelA1(ind1,SUBJECT_VAL_COL));
    xlswrite('File.xls', {'Radiobutton: '},'Sheet1',GenerateExcelA1(ind1,RADIO_TAG_COL));
    xlswrite('File.xls', {Radiobutton},'Sheet1',GenerateExcelA1(ind1,RADIO_VAL_COL)); 
end
```

Also consider [`xlswrite1`](http://www.mathworks.com/matlabcentral/fileexchange/10465-xlswrite1) which is supposed to be faster.

Comment: I use [`xlscol`](http://www.mathworks.com/matlabcentral/fileexchange/28343-column-converter-for-excel/content/xlscol.m) to convert to Excel notation for `xlswrite`, and I recommend it.

Comment: Sorry for the late reply, I tried testing out with you code but I got a few errors. How do I go about declaring numLines? Is it as a number like number of lines it is going to take up? When I input a number for numLines, I got the following error aft that: Undefined function 'GenerateExcelA1' for input arguments of type 'double'. From the way i read the code, isnt Radiobutton's data going to replace SubjectID data? I am quite new so I dont really understand much about your coding sorry >.<

Comment: @user4514279 - You are right about the overwriting, I forgot to update the numbers on the 2nd pair when writing the code. Yes @ numLines - the amount of lines you want to write should be known (either computed during runtime or hard-coded). See updated answer. You should read a bit about the structure of a MATLAB project (i.e. how to work with multiple `.m` files for example). Good luck!

Comment: Currently, I have been playing around with the code, but it seems to keep overwriting the code... Is there a way to go abt doing this?

It seems to be multiplying the output with the same number of lines as numLine >.<

Comment: See the comment about "make sure data is available"? It assumes that the contents of `name` and `Radiobutton` get updated somehow for every iteration. If those are vectors you can access them with e.g. `name{ind1}` etc.

Comment: I use my own simple function [`excel_column`](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/31860247/how-to-find-the-last-column-index-in-excel-with-matlab/31862155#31862155) to convert column indices to excel alphanumeric notation.

Comment: Is it possible to continue to have it input data without having for those to get updated after every iteration?

And regarding xlswrite1, I change line 2 to Excel=evalin('caller','Excel')