# how can I access cells in excel sheet using only numbers without alphabets like A1 or B2

Tags: excel, matlab

I'm writing Matlab script to access data from excel sheet. I don't want to access cell using alphabets (e.g. B1). But I'm unable to access cell using cell(row,column).

Could anyone help me out?

Comment: Try [this](https://www.mathworks.com/matlabcentral/fileexchange/28343-column-converter-for-excel).

Comment: or [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/31860247/how-to-find-the-last-column-index-in-excel-with-matlab/31862155#31862155) to get you started ...

Answer (score 0):

This set of functions will convert any number to its equivalent Excel column:

```
Cletter = @(c) char(mod(c,26)+(mod(c,26)==0)*26+64);
AZbase = @(c) fliplr(cumprod([c repmat(1/26,1,2)]));
xlCOL = @(c) Cletter(nonzeros(floor((AZbase(c)-circshift(mod(AZbase(c),26)==0,-1)).*(c>[702 26 0]))).');
```

You can combine them to one function, but I prefer to leave them separated so it won't be too hard to understand how they work.

For example:

```
>> xlCOL(6504)
ans =
    'IPD'
```

Now you can extend them with another pair of functions to build the range string:

```
RC2AB = @(row,col) [xlCOL(col) int2str(row)]; 
makeRange = @(c1,c2) [RC2AB(c1(1),c1(2)) ':' RC2AB(c2(1),c2(2))];
```

(again, I prefer to leave them separated...)

for example:

```
>> makeRange([12,321],[46,951])
ans =
    'LI12:AJO46'
```

Note the in `makeRange` the input is two 2-element vectors, one for the first cell in range and one for the last. In each cell, the first element is the row, and the second is the column.

You can verify this result using the formula [`ADDRESS(row_num, column_num)`](https://support.office.com/en-us/article/address-function-d0c26c0d-3991-446b-8de4-ab46431d4f89) in Excel.

This is only for simple use. It does not perform any checks that this is a valid range (i.e. that the second cell is not above/left to the first cell and that the column/row number is not out of range).

---

I took this question more as a challenge than as a real problem. There is no doubt that writing a small m-file with a function (like in the [linked answer](https://stackoverflow.com/q/31860247/2627163)) would be more simple. But I had to find a way to complete this in a few anonymous functions.
Still, this answer does not provide any explanation on how they work, as I don't think that someone will be interested in it, but if you do - just leave a comment, and I'll add some explanations.

Comment: Hi Thanks for the reply.I want to access beyond 'Z'.How to access?

Comment: @pavankumar see my edit for support in all Excel columns