# How to read a row in excel while taking cell number from a variable in Matlab?

Tags: arrays, matlab, matrix

I would like to read a row from excel file in Matlab. The row's staring and end columns are defined but I would like to use a variable to define the row number. I have tried the following:

```
row_no = 50;
x = xlsread('yourfile.xlsx', 'sheet', ['B50:EHI' num2str(row_no)]);
```

The above code allows the use of variable `row_no` to define the end cell `EHI50`. But can this also be done for referring to the starting cell `B50`?

Comment: `[ 'B' num2str(row_no) ':EHI' num2str(row_no) ]` ?

Comment: If you are working with Excel you might find [this](https://www.mathworks.com/matlabcentral/fileexchange/28343-column-converter-for-excel) submission useful

Comment: or [this one](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/31860247/how-to-find-the-last-column-index-in-excel-with-matlab/31862155#31862155). It is simpler, not bidirectional, but it can be simpler to include inline in some custom code.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can include it in the same way:

```
row_start = 50;
row_end = 50;    
x = xlsread('yourfile.xlsx', 'sheet', ['B' num2str(row_start) ':EHI' num2str(row_no)]);
```

Of course `row_start` and `row_end` can be the same variable if they're the same number.

You could also use `sprintf` to tidy this up a bit

```
x = xlsread('yourfile.xlsx', 'sheet', sprintf('B%.0f:EHI%.0f', row_start, row_end) );
```

Comment: I know in these cases the results are similar, but wouldn't it be preferable to use `'%d'` instead of `'%.0f'` ?

Comment: @Hoki define "preferable"?

Comment: "Preferable" if you wrote your post with a teaching intent. You are not discussing tricks of the trade with someone at your level, you are teaching something new to someone. Knowing which type of variable he is going to need (only integers in his case) is important in programming, so teach him to use the format specifier intended for thoses (I know Matlab casting everything to `double` meddles things up but one more reason to sensitize people to know what type of variable they use and choose the right tool for it).

Comment: @Hoki umm okay then... I'm using a double `row_start` or `row_end`, and using the format specifer `%.0f` to ensure this is inserted to 0 decimal places (i.e. as an integer). I default to using the `f` format specifier for numeric variables because it is more flexible and clearer to me; I can see the value will be written as an integer without having to remember the specifier for integers. I don't think this is a best-practise thing, I think it's a preference thing.

Comment: I agree it's a preference thing, once you understand all the options you are free to choose. My concern was that the OP might not know all the options so starting with the most flexible (but also the most confusing for beginners) format specifier might give him bad habits.