# How to modify my MatLab script to correctly write to Excel?

Tags: matlab, xls

So I basically have a small script in MatLab which I'm using in a much larger program. This script essentially keeps writing data to an Excel file.

The script writes data horizontally across cells and is as follows:

```
function writevar(x,k,filename)
    col = char(64+k);
    N = size(x,1);
    Rg = sprintf([col '1:' col '%i' ],N);
    xlswrite(filename,x,Rg)
end
```

The script works perfectly when writing data between columns A-Z. However it crashes once it reaches column Z. How can I modify the script so that it can keep writing beyond column Z to AA, AB, etc (it needs to go right the way down to CR).

Thanks.

Comment: Your problem is the line `char(64+k)`. Once you reach the ASCII code for `Z` (90) you will get the ASCII code of `[` (91).
You need to handle this case adding a second char on the left and reset the first one to 64 (ASCII for 'A'). This way you will get without problems up to ZZ.

Comment: @BlackAdder Aah I see, thank you!

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Convert Excel Column Number to Column Name in Matlab](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/14261648/convert-excel-column-number-to-column-name-in-matlab)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are correctly processing a values of `k` in the range `[1, 26]`. Presumably column `AA` would be `k = 27` in your input, so you need to do some special math on that. Here is a snippet that should convert `k` to a column name in the general case:

```
k = k - 1; % Convert to zero-based for ease of processing
col = '';
while k ~= 0
    % Prepend higher digits
    col = [char(mod(k, 26) + 65) col];
    k = floor(k / 26);
end
```

Answer (score 1):

One way to handle this (and see BlackAdder's comment) would be

```
function writevar(x,k,filename)
  if (k > 26) {
    col = [char(64+ceil(k/26)) char(64+mod(k,26))];
  else
    col = [char(64+k);
  end
  N = size(x,1);
  Rg = sprintf([col '1:' col '%i' ],N);
  xlswrite(filename,x,Rg)
end
```

Comment: This solutions only goes to column 'ZZ'. Otherwise see Mad Physicist's answer.

Comment: Thank you for your answer! It's still helpful to see how it's done appreciate it!

Comment: I strongly suspect that your code won't work. Last time I checked, curly braces are only used for cell arrays in MATLAB.